# Find Out What Objects Garbage Collector Is Releasing:

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to find memory leaks in a program I did not design (I'm new to the project). As it is quite a large program, I am having some trouble. I have tried a few profilers, and most of them hang or crash when attempting to follow the allocation stack trace to see which objects are taking up all of the memory.

I am running `System.gc();` in a Thread and attempting to find out what exactly it is releasing/freeing. From the profiler, I can see that it **is** releasing, but I need to know what it is releasing.

Is there some way to get information at runtime from the garbage collector as to which objects it is releasing/freeing?

If not, or if this is a bad way to even think about trying to approach this, any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: A profiler is what you need. Find one that works. Or work out why the ones you tried failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a memory profiler to find a memory leak.  You can start with VisualVM. this may find your problem, but if it doesn't try an evaluation version of a commercial profiler like YourKit.

These tools can not only tell you what is being discarded but where it is being creating in the first place.  It has a graphical interface so you can see the biggest or most numerous.

Comment: These look like much better profilers than what I've used. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way of finding memory leaks is triggering a heap dump by either waiting for it to happen (following an OOM) using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` as a JVM launch parameter or 'on demand' using jsconsole/jmap.

Then run (the usually large) dump file through the excellent MAT
http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: Memory analysis can also be done by another eclipse plugin 'TPTP'. http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html

Answer (score 0):

i don't have the exact solution of which object will be realized by System.gc();

but JAVA provides built in GUI tool facility to **JAVA monitoring and Management Console**

you found jconsole in java/bin folder to run it: use command

```
cd $JAVA_HOME/bin
./jconsole
```